# infinite scroll using laravel and vue request not sent to display data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

good day;
 i new in `vue.js`
 i have simple problem  when i using infinite scroll  i make configuration  as below but when page reloaded it must send request to data base to show data when page =1  this request not sent 
i want help to get it work
this is my 
this is service component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- start covr-page --------------------- -->
        <div class="covr-page">
            <h2>خدمات لوجستية متكاملة </h2>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- end covr-page --------------------- -->

        <!-- start servic --------------------- -->
        <div class="servic sections">
            <div class="container">
                <h3 class="start-title">
                    <img src="/images/start-title.png" alt="">
                    خدمات لوجستية متكاملة
                </h3>

                <div class="row">

                    <div v-for="service,key in list" class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <a href="order-service.html">
                            <div class="email-signature">
                                <div class="signature-details">
                                    <div class="signature-img">
                                        <img :src="`upload/${service.icon}`" alt="">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="contant-serv">
                                    <h4>{{service.ar_name}}</h4>
                                    <p>
                                        {{service.ar_description}}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <infinite-loading @distance="100" @infinite="infiniteHandler"></infinite-loading>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

this is my route

Route::get('/Services', 'ServicesController@Services');
this is my js code

```
<script>


    export default {
        name: "Services",

        data: function () {
            return {
                list: [],
                page:1


            }
        },
        mounted(){
           // this.infiniteHandler()

            // axios.get('/Services')
            //     .then((response) =>{
            //         this.list=response.data
            //     }).catch((error) =>this.errors=error.response.data.errors );
        },
        methods: {
            infiniteHandler($state) {
                this.$http.get('/Services?page='+this.page)
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json();
                    }).then(data => {
                    $.each(data.data, (key, value)=> {
                        this.list.push(value);
                    });
                    $state.loaded();

                });

                this.page = this.page + 1;
            },
        },




    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not declared vue-infinite-loading

```
import InfiniteLoading from 'vue-infinite-loading';

export default {
    components: {
     InfiniteLoading,
    },
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @David Buck yes sorry :)